# Get size_bytes for Query Results

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to get the size_bytes of a query result without saving the result to a table. 
1. I noticed that we can use use

```
select size_bytes from [datasets__TABLES__]
```

to get the size of tables in a dataset. 
2. what I am trying to do is kind of this,

```
select size_bytes from 
( some query )
```

Is that a way to do this? avoiding get the actual result, only get the byte size of the result?

Thank you.

Comment: to get size of result you actually need to generate result first! so, no, unfortunately - you cannot avoid getting actual result first! if you would explain your use case  - we might be able to find some workaround for it

Comment: I c, thank you Mikhail, then I would generate the result first or may think some other ways. The situation is, I would like to calculate the data consumption for different circumstances, and this will cross through several tables, so that I am thinking about getting the size from the result directly without saving to the big query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get size of result you actually need to generate result first! so, no, unfortunately - you cannot avoid getting actual result first

if you really want/need to avoid producing/paying for result  - you can try to estimate result size based on original size of your data (see more here: [Find out the amount of space each field takes in Google Big Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086078/5221944)) and estimated number of rows in result

Comment: Thank you for you answers again, Mikhail. It is not about estimating the processed data size using dry-run, but estimating the size of result after processing. I think I  will generate the tables first and then get the size.

Comment: i provided link because it shows how to find size of original data w/o actually running any query. as I explained in my answer - if you know nature/size of your original data, query and you have an idea about how many rows in output  - based on this you can try estimate size of output. But sure - running relevant examples and getting sizes from there is the most straightforward and exact way I think

Comment: Totally agreed, according to the size of the original table, and output rows, i can definitely estimate the size of output result. either way will work. Thx